# What's the difference between deploying MySQL/MariaDB connector and adding it as a module?

Tags: java, mysql, mariadb, wildfly

When connecting to MySQL/MariaDB database on Wildfly using `standalone.xml`, I have come across 2 approaches to using the driver:

1. You can put the connector jar (such as `mariadb-java-client-2.4.2.jar`) into standalone/deployments folder and then in `standalone.xml`, on your Wildfly installation, your would reference the driver with a line such as:

   ```
   <driver>mariadb-java-client-2.4.2.jar</driver>**
   ```

   in your datasource configuration
2. You add the driver as a module in Wildfly under `modules/system/layers/base` by creating a `module.xml` and putting the relevant jar in the folder. In your Wildfly `standalone.xml` you would then add it as a driver under the datasources, something like the following:

   ```
   <driver name="mariadb" module="org.mariadb.jdbc">

   <xa-datasource-class>org.mariadb.jdbc.MariaDbDataSource</xa-datasource-class>

   </driver>
   ```

   You would then reference the driver with a line such as:

   ```
    <driver>mariadb</driver>
   ```

   in your datasource configuration.

What is the difference between the 2 approaches, and when should you use them or are they the same (same speed, same stability, same resources)?

Comment: One doesn't tie a given jar name and version to the data source, so easier to upgrade if you have multiple sources